# How to loop through data so insert each bigquery row Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery

In this function, it is taking cron times (expected start time) from one bigquery table (expected_sla) parsing it and the end time from that same table and inserting those two into 2 fields called expected start date and expected end time fields in the sla_table table. I want it to where it checks the dag_id and depending on the dag id insert the parsed expected start time and expected end time. Right now its just creating new rows on bigquery with these 2 dates and having all the other fields as null. I want it to where it will loop through and insert the appropriate expected start time and end time for each dag depending on the dag_id.

[BigQuery table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLtB0.jpg)

```js
(async function () {
    const runs = [
        {
            start_date: '2022-06-26T23:00:00.742495+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-06-27T14:10:23.108401+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-25T23:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'EFS-Winning-Route-daily-batch'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-07T21:20:00.566888+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-07T23:20:55.250911+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-06T21:20:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'ft-parm-trumping-daily'

        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-03T14:00:00.779718+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-03T14:00:41.250433+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-26T14:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'ft-parm-trumping-weekly'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-08T04:00:01.038023+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-08T05:08:59.597408+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-07T04:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'IP_MASTER'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-08T13:45:00.757997+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-08T14:02:48.050405+00:00',
            state: 'success',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-07T13:45:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'IPP_CYCLE_PARMS'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-08T02:00:00.821824+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-08T02:02:06.027268+00:00',
            state: 'success',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-07T02:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'ipp-daily-backups'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-07T23:00:01.313332+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-07T23:02:37.032427+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-06T23:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'oclt-leadtime-daily'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-08T13:00:00.471935+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-08T13:00:49.819534+00:00',
            state: 'success',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-07T13:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'ope-metrics'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-07T21:30:00.682954+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-07T21:33:29.885878+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-06T21:30:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'parm-lite-daily'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-08T08:00:01.756909+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-08T08:35:55.043131+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-07-07T08:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'parm-lite-data-migration'
        },
        {
            start_date: '2022-07-03T09:00:00.825694+00:00',
            end_date: '2022-07-03T09:10:31.680879+00:00',
            state: 'failed',
            dag_run_id: 'scheduled__2022-06-26T09:00:00+00:00',
            dag_id: 'parm-lite-sunday-push-instance'
        }
    ];

async function determineStartEnd(result){
    dagID = result ? result.dag_id : 0
    console.log(dagID)
    job = await bqConnection().query(`SELECT * FROM \`np-inventory-planning-thd.IPP_SLA.expected_sla\` where dag_id = "${dagID}"`)
    cronTime = job[0][0].cron_time
    endTime = job[0][0].expected_end_time
    var interval = parser.parseExpression(cronTime);
    const d = new Date(interval.next().toString()).toISOString()
    //var timeStamp = d.getTime();
    //const parts = interval.next().toString().split(' ');
    expectedStartDate = d
    console.log(d);
    console.log(endTime)
}
        const date = {expected_start_date:expectedStartDate,expected_end_date:endTime}
        for (let run of runs) {
            await determineStartEnd(run);
            await bqConnection()
                .dataset('IPP_SLA')
                .table('sla_table')
                .insert(date);
        }
}

)
();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your table contains values for the espected_start_date & expected_end_date. The other fields all contain `NULL` values.

Try the below code changes:

```
        //const date = {expected_start_date:expectedStartDate,expected_end_date:endTime}
        for (let run of runs) {
            await determineStartEnd(run);
            run['expected_start_date'] = expectedStartDate;
            run['expected_end_date'] = endTime;
            await bqConnection()
                .dataset('IPP_SLA')
                .table('sla_table')
                .insert(run);
        }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this but I want it to to insert the expected start and end dates by the dag id. So for example if a dag id is "dag1" then it has to insert the expected start and end dates for that specific dag and so there are multiple dags with different "dag_id"s and i want to insert the correct expected start and end times to the right dag_id's. All the expected start time cron data and expected end time data are in another table i just want to use that as a config table and update that data into this new sla_table table